# Why is this pg query so slow? How can I make it faster?

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing, query-performance

This is the query:

```
(SELECT * 
FROM url 
WHERE domain = 'youtube.com' 
  AND timestamp > NOW() - INTERVAL '24 hours' 
ORDER BY likes DESC LIMIT 10) 
UNION 
(SELECT * 
FROM url 
WHERE domain = 'twitter.com' 
  AND timestamp > NOW() - INTERVAL '24 hours' 
ORDER BY likes DESC LIMIT 10) 
UNION 
(SELECT * 
FROM url 
WHERE domain = 'reddit.com' 
  AND timestamp > NOW() - INTERVAL '24 hours' 
ORDER BY likes DESC LIMIT 10) 
ORDER BY timestamp DESC
```

This is the `EXPLAIN ANALYZE`.

```
Sort  (cost=20460.17..20460.25 rows=30 width=497) (actual time=5161.013..5161.015 rows=30 loops=1)
  Sort Key: url."timestamp" DESC
  Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 53kB
  ->  HashAggregate  (cost=20459.14..20459.44 rows=30 width=497) (actual time=5160.709..5160.738 rows=30 loops=1)
        Group Key: url.url, url.domain, url.title, url.views, url.likes, url.dislikes, url.comments, url.shares, url.links_to_url, url."user", url.thumbnail_url, url.is_collection, url.image_url, url.video_url, url.audio_url, url.width, url.height, url.body, url.source, url."timestamp", url.created_at, url.updated_at, url.duration_seconds, url.tags, url.channel
        ->  Append  (cost=0.43..20457.26 rows=30 width=497) (actual time=0.514..5160.073 rows=30 loops=1)
              ->  Limit  (cost=0.43..18150.71 rows=10 width=1177) (actual time=0.513..28.599 rows=10 loops=1)
                    ->  Index Scan Backward using "url-likes-index" on url  (cost=0.43..816763.00 rows=450 width=1177) (actual time=0.511..28.594 rows=10 loops=1)
                          Filter: (((domain)::text = 'youtube.com'::text) AND ("timestamp" > (now() - '24:00:00'::interval)))
                          Rows Removed by Filter: 11106
              ->  Limit  (cost=0.43..859.82 rows=10 width=1177) (actual time=2330.390..5033.214 rows=10 loops=1)
                    ->  Index Scan Backward using "url-likes-index" on url url_1  (cost=0.43..816763.00 rows=9504 width=1177) (actual time=2330.388..5033.200 rows=10 loops=1)
                          Filter: (((domain)::text = 'twitter.com'::text) AND ("timestamp" > (now() - '24:00:00'::interval)))
                          Rows Removed by Filter: 1667422
              ->  Limit  (cost=0.43..1446.28 rows=10 width=1177) (actual time=64.748..98.228 rows=10 loops=1)
                    ->  Index Scan Backward using "url-likes-index" on url url_2  (cost=0.43..816763.00 rows=5649 width=1177) (actual time=64.745..98.220 rows=10 loops=1)
                          Filter: (((domain)::text = 'reddit.com'::text) AND ("timestamp" > (now() - '24:00:00'::interval)))
                          Rows Removed by Filter: 26739
Planning Time: 3.006 ms
Execution Time: 5162.201 ms
```

And if you're interested in running it yourself, [go to this link](https://www.tagsyo.com/q?q=%28SELECT%20%2A%20FROM%20url%20WHERE%20domain%20%3D%20%27youtube.com%27%20AND%20timestamp%20%3E%20NOW%28%29%20-%20INTERVAL%20%2724%20hours%27%20ORDER%20BY%20likes%20DESC%20LIMIT%2010%29%20UNION%20%28SELECT%20%2A%20FROM%20url%20WHERE%20domain%20%3D%20%27twitter.com%27%20AND%20timestamp%20%3E%20NOW%28%29%20-%20INTERVAL%20%2724%20hours%27%20ORDER%20BY%20likes%20DESC%20LIMIT%2010%29%20UNION%20%28SELECT%20%2A%20FROM%20url%20WHERE%20domain%20%3D%20%27reddit.com%27%20AND%20timestamp%20%3E%20NOW%28%29%20-%20INTERVAL%20%2724%20hours%27%20ORDER%20BY%20likes%20DESC%20LIMIT%2010%29%20ORDER%20BY%20timestamp%20DESC%20%21hugecards).

I see that a million twitter rows are being filtered, but I'm not sure how to avoid it. I have a `timestamp` index and I was hoping that would be used instead of sorting by `likes` and scanning the whole thing. Does this mean I need a composite index? Is there a way to make the planner use both indexes instead of making another?

p.s. I think I goofed with the primary key being the url. It makes the indexes needlessly larger.

Comment: `UNION ALL` instead of `UNION` will probably improve it a bit.

Comment: It's hard to judge because the numbers are jittery, but it might be a 5% change. Thank you for mentioning it.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name . . . Although a best practice, `union` versus `union all` on 30 rows isn't going to make a big difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest writing the query like this:

```
SELECT ufiltered.*
FROM (SELECT url.*,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY domain ORDER BY likes DESC) AS seqnum
      FROM url 
      WHERE domain IN ('youtube.com', 'twitter.com', 'reddit.com') AND
            timestamp > NOW() - INTERVAL '24 hours'
    ) AS ufiltered
WHERE seqnum <= 10
ORDER BY timestamp DESC
```

For this, I would recommend an index on `url(timestamp, domain, likes)`.

Comment: I had to edit because `seqnum` wasn't defined, but this query seems comparably fast, doesn't resort to the `views+0` trick, and it's about 100 characters shorter. I'll take it.

Comment: When I used this with `1 year` I got `QueryFailedError: temporary file size exceeds temp_file_limit (3193019kB)`. So I ended up using the original query from the question as is, with no forcing of indexes. The different time frames each require a different index.

Answer (score 2):

PostgreSQL tries to use the index on `likes` to avoid a sort to get the top 10 results, but it has to discard many rows to get there.

Perhaps that execution plan is the best one, perhaps not.

Follow these steps:

1. Run `ANALYZE` on thee table and see if that solves the problem.
2. If not, create an index on `(domain, timestamp)` (in that order!) and see if that improves matters.
3. If that isn't sufficient, either

   - drop the index on `likes` (if you can)

   or

   - change `ORDER BY likes` into `ORDER BY likes + 0`.

If all that doesn't make it better, then your original query plan was the best, and all you can do is use more RAM in the hope that more of your data is in cache.

Comment: Just tried `ORDER BY likes + 0` and that already causes pg to avoid the `likes` index and takes me from 20 seconds down to 0.25. I'll test out your other ideas, but that already deserves the points. Thank you!

Comment: I suggested that last because it is the least elegant solution.

Comment: `ANALYZE url` didn't seem to do anything. My indexes are a bit big, so I'm a bit shy on that, but might try it later.

Comment: Well, then go with the third option.